# Working with canvas and bitmaps in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to use Canvas and Bitmaps to draw in my activity, but I am not getting a hold of things like:

1. When is the onDraw function called.
2. How can we call onDraw function again after making changes. (`this.invalidate` does not seem to do the trick).
3. How to have something drawn on the canvas and make changes to it and later refresh it.

Can someone explain these? (Example code would be an extra plus). Thanks :)

Comment: Hello! Could you please post some code of what you are trying to do? invalidate() should be the way to go (at least, one of them) for both the second and the third question; and then onDraw is called whenever the view needs to be updated, which again, can be triggered by invalidate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. onDraw() is initially called by the system sometime after inflating the layout containing the View. If you setContentView() in your onCreate(), for example, you have at least until onCreate() returns before it will be drawn because the UI thread must go idle in order for a draw to occur.
2. invalidate() is the way to do this. Don't call it from within onDraw or you'll be in an infinite loop.
3. Again, use invalidate() whenever you need a redraw. That is its purpose.